# Ruby tries to load from gem from older version

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I'm trying to run an [script](https://github.com/globalcitizen/taoup) that calls the `ansi` gem with the following line:

```
require 'ansi/code'
```

However, when I try running it, I get the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- ansi/code (LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from ./taoup:4:in `<main>'
```

I tried to make sure I run Ruby v2.6.5 and reinstalled the dependencies afterward.

```
→ rbenv versions
  system
  2.1.3
  2.2.1
* 2.6.5 (set by /Users/ricky/.rbenv/version)

→ gem install ansi
Successfully installed ansi-1.5.0
Parsing documentation for ansi-1.5.0
Done installing documentation for ansi after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

For reference, it seems that rubygems is running at v.2.6.5.

```
→ gem env   
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.5 (2019-10-01 patchlevel 114) [x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ricky/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ricky/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/ricky/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/ricky/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/ricky/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Users/ricky/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/ricky/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/ricky/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "install" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
     - "update" => "--no-rdoc --no-ri"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
```

I think I need to direct the execution environment to use my intended version of Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, looks like the script was pointing to a specific installation of Ruby, as specified here:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
```

This version of ruby was not the one I intended to run on. It is a different version afterall:

```
→ /usr/bin/ruby --version 
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
```

So I made a quick and dirty fix on the script by rewriting the Shebang declaration like this:

```
#!/Users/ricky/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/bin/ruby
```

If anyone knows a version-agnostic way to fix this dependency, please let me know!